# Change bootstrap validation message color to red

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, forms

I have a form that posts an error message if an invalid email is entered. I'd like the error message text to be changed to red. How can I do this?

```js
$('#subscribe-form').bootstrapValidator({
  live: 'disabled',
  fields: {
    email: {
      validators: {
        emailAddress: {
          message: 'Please enter a valid email address'
        }
      }
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form role="form" id="subscribe-form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control custom-email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-large custom-button">Sign up !</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Try this http://formvalidation.io/examples/changing-success-error-colors/

Comment: As a heads up - Validator hasn't updated its support for BS4 yet and some of the naming conventions have changed.  If you end up adopting BS4 in your project there are CSS workarounds in GitHub to address error-coloring.

Comment: @f78xd23 this link no longer exists. FYI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add below css in your code

```
.has-error .help-block {
  color: red;
}
```

```js
$('#subscribe-form').bootstrapValidator({
  live: 'disabled',
  fields: {
    email: {
      validators: {
        emailAddress: {
          message: 'Please enter a valid email address'
        }
      }
    },
  }
});
```

```css
.has-error .help-block {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-validator/0.5.3/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>
<form role="form" id="subscribe-form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control custom-email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-large custom-button">Sign up !</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

If Bootstrap is added correctly you should already get error text as red. If not, this will fix that.

```
small.help-block {
   color: #F44336 !important;
}
```

```js
$('#subscribe-form').bootstrapValidator({
  live: 'disabled',
  fields: {
    email: {
      validators: {
        emailAddress: {
          message: 'Please enter a valid email address'
        }
      }
    },
  }
});
```

```css
small.help-block {
  color: #F44336 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-validator/0.5.3/js/bootstrapValidator.js"></script>

<form role="form" id="subscribe-form">

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control custom-email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address">
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-large custom-button"> Sign up ! </button>
</form>
```